# Hard disk recognised but doesn't show up

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have this strange issues with my Seagate external drive that has important data. When I connect my HDD via usb, I can see the device appear in the tray as seen below:

[image: here]

But however, it doesn't appear on device manager or `diskpart`. Another issue I face is that my pc takes too long (or never) to shut down or turn on when the HDD is connected. I have tried changing the usb and also tried connecting the HDD to other pcs but no luck.

The other day the device appeared on `diskpart` and the device manager as unallocated space:

[image: diskpart]

When I tried to initialize the disk as MBR or GPT, I get the error message as the "device is not ready". Like this:

[image: this]

Comment: Does it do any noise like clicking? Are there errors related to the disk in Event Viewer?

Comment: Well, sounds like the USB bridge (in the enclosure/"caddy") is having problem in talking to the actual drive. There might be a glimpse chance in replacing the enclosure. (But it can be tricky since some "groups 512b blocks in to 4k ones but some don't.)

Comment: There is no visible or audible damage to the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have backup, as it doesn't look good for this disk.

For diagnostics, get the SMART attributes of the disk and
[Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1807011/edit)
them into your post, for us to have a look.
If you don't have a product for that, you could try
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
and
[CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/?PageSpeed=noscript).
If both products fail to get this data, this is already a very bad sign.

You might also try
[Seagate SeaTools](https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)
to diagnose if the disk is still alive.
This webpage also allows to find a firmware download for your disk
by entering its serial number, which might help if the firmware
itself is damaged and needs to be repaired.

If nothing works for you, and if the data on the disk is important
and irreplaceable, only a professional disk recovery company can
help further (these services are not cheap).

Comment: Well, I think it is dead. Nothing seems to work now and I am getting a blue screen error when I connect it. Thanks anyways :)